# Python file dialog issue

Tags: python, dialog, text-files

I am trying to use Tkinter to choose a file and then import that filename into an argument to pass in a function. The program simply stops after the file is chosen. I included a print statement just to see if it returns the path and it does so I am not sure why it won't work in the function.

```
#Main

from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog


fileOpen = Tk()
fileOpen.withdraw() #hiding tkinter window

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Open file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])

if file_path != "":
   print "you chose file with path:", file_path

else:
   print "you didn't open anything!"

master.quit()

print file_path   


spaceParser (file_path,'r','/Users/Desktop/TygerTygerParsed.txt','w')
```

Comment: `master` isn't defined in your script, so when it gets to `master.quit()` it will raise: `NameError: name 'master' is not defined`.

Answer (score 3):

This (shortened version) works just fine:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

fileOpen = Tk()
fileOpen.withdraw() #hiding tkinter window

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(
    title="Open file", filetypes=[("txt file",".txt"),("All files",".*")])

if file_path != "":
   print "you chose file with path:", file_path

else:
   print "you didn't open anything!"

print file_path
```

So I'm guessing your program is halting on

```
master.quit()
```

Comment: it works fine, but it will not pass the file name into the function

Comment: Can you show us the code the defines `spaceParser`? If the program is not halting on `master.quit`, then the problem is probably in `spaceParser`. All the other code you showed us should work fine.