# Stuck on python open file method

Tags: python, user-interface, interface

I'm trying to build an assembler in Python 2.7, but I'm stuck at the first step.  Can anyone give me an example of how to write code that would open up a dialog box to select a file like with the Java filechooser method?

I'm familiar with the open method, but the problem with that is that you have to specify the location within the method. I need to be able to pick any file, not just a specified file. I know that "raw_input" may have something to do with this but I'm not completely sure how to implement it, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6904731/367273

Comment: Why is the first step in writing an assembler to open a dialog box?

Answer (score 2):

The code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6904731/367273) works just fine on my machine.